# Convergence in $L^p_{loc}$ implies convergence of a subsequence in $L^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, pointwise-convergence

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded or unbounded. Suppose we have a sequence $\{f_n\} \in L^p_{loc}(\Omega)$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^p_{loc}(\Omega)$ for $f \in L^p_{loc}(\Omega)$.

Now suppose further that $f \in L^\infty(\Omega)$. Since $L^\infty(\Omega) \subset L^p_{loc}(\Omega)$, I am wondering if it is possible to always extract a subsequence of $\{f_n\}$, call it $\{f_{n_k}\}$, such that $f_{n_k} \rightarrow f$ in $L^\infty(\Omega)$. I think this is possible but I cannot convince myself that we can always choose a convergence subsequence such that all its elements belong to $L^\infty$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry I should have been more specific. I meant convergence in $L^\infty$ implies pointwise convergence a.e.

Comment: @AnneBauval I have corrected my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. Take $f_n = \chi_{ [1/n,\ 1+1/n] }$.

Comment: Doesn't each $f_n$ belong to $L^\infty$?

Comment: @AnneBauval If we take the sequence itself as a subsequence don't we have $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^\infty$?

Comment: No: $\|f_n-f\|_\infty=1$.